# Question about conditional calculation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, conditional-statements

I have this formula, I wanted to turn this into pandas calculation,
the formula is very easy: 
`NEW = A(where v=1) + A(where v=3) + A(where v=5)`

I have a data frame like this:

```
Type subType value   A           NEW
 X    a       1      3         =3+9+9=21
 X    a       3      9  
 X    a       5      9
 X    b       1      4         =4+5+0=9
 X    b       3      5 
 X    b       5      0
 Y    a       1      1         =1+2+3=6
 Y    a       3      2  
 Y    a       5      3
 Y    b       1      4         =4+5+2=11
 Y    b       3      5 
 Y    b       5      2
```

Two questions:

1. I know I can just write down the calculation with the specified cell, but I want the code looks nicer, is there other ways to get the value?
2. Because there will be only two results for X & Y, how can I add them into my original dataframe for further calculation? (my thought is not to add them in the dataframe and just use the value whenever it's necessary for future calculation)
   Quite new to coding, any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: df.groupby('X').A.sum()?

Comment: `df.groupby('X')['A'].transform('sum')` if you need to keep original index.

Comment: seems I can't use ```groupby('X')``` directly, it gave me error, I tried ```groupby['Type']('X')``` still not working, any thoughts?

Comment: use the column name `df.groupby('Type')['A'].sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['X','X','X','Y','Y','Y'], 'value':[1,3,5,1,3,5], 'A':[3,9,4,0,2,2]})

>>> df
  Type  value  A
0    X      1  3
1    X      3  9
2    X      5  4
3    Y      1  0
4    Y      3  2
5    Y      5  2

>>> df.groupby('Type')['A'].sum()
Type
X    16
Y     4

>>> ur_dict = df.groupby('Type')['A'].sum().to_dict()
>>> df['NEW'] = df['Type'].map(ur_dict)
>>> df
  Type  value  A  NEW
0    X      1  3   16
1    X      3  9   16
2    X      5  4   16
3    Y      1  0    4
4    Y      3  2    4
5    Y      5  2    4
```

Hope this helps.

### Edit to answer additional inquiry:

You are mapping tuple keys to a series, that will give you an error. You should shift the columns you need to map your dictionary into as index before doing the mapping.

See below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['X','X','X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'], 'subType':['a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b','b'],'value':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5],'A':[3,9,9,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,2]})
>>> df
   Type subType  value  A
0     X       a      1  3
1     X       a      3  9
2     X       a      5  9
3     X       b      1  4
4     X       b      3  5
5     X       b      5  0
6     Y       a      1  1
7     Y       a      3  2
8     Y       a      5  3
9     Y       b      1  4
10    Y       b      3  5
11    Y       b      5  2

>>> df.groupby(['Type', 'subType'])['A'].sum()
Type  subType
X     a          21
      b           9
Y     a           6
      b          11
Name: A, dtype: int64
>>> ur_dict = df.groupby(['Type', 'subType'])['A'].sum().to_dict()
>>> ur_dict
{('X', 'a'): 21, ('X', 'b'): 9, ('Y', 'a'): 6, ('Y', 'b'): 11}

>>> df['NEW'] = df.set_index(['Type', 'subType']).index.map(ur_dict)
>>> df
   Type subType  value  A  NEW
0     X       a      1  3   21
1     X       a      3  9   21
2     X       a      5  9   21
3     X       b      1  4    9
4     X       b      3  5    9
5     X       b      5  0    9
6     Y       a      1  1    6
7     Y       a      3  2    6
8     Y       a      5  3    6
9     Y       b      1  4   11
10    Y       b      3  5   11
11    Y       b      5  2   11
```

---

Comment: Hi thanks, this works! Just wondering what if I have a column 'subType', how can I adjust the ```groupby```? I've updated in my question. Many thanks!

Comment: @Cecilia `df.groupby(col)` allows you to group your levels (here: X and Y) in the factor "col" (here: Type). Change simply the name of the column to group another factor. `df.groupby(col1)[col2]` will return the elements of the column `col2` which were grouped according to `col1`, before to be summed here. At the contrary, you can group several columns using `df.groupby([col1, col2, ...])` to be more precised in your grouping. If your question is related to a MultiIndex, that's another topic.

Comment: I just tried ```ur_dict = df.groupby('Type')['A'].sum().to_dict()
>>> df['NEW'] = df['Type'].map(ur_dict)``` but the values for the new column are all ```NaN```

Comment: Is it because the data type is float instead of int? Or is it because I added 'subType' column? I tried ```df['NEW'] = df['Type', 'subType'].map(ur_dict)```Still not working, please help...

Comment: when you use more than two columns, the `to_dict()` method will create a dictionary where the keys are `tuples` which means when using the `map` method it expects to look for those `tuple` values in order to give the dictionary counterpart values. Try printing `df.groupby(['Type', 'subtype'])['A'].sum().to_dict()` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Hi, I tried ```to.dict()``` and it returns something like ```{('X', 'a'): 6.0, ('X', 'b'): 2.35, ('Y', 'a'): 1.05, ('Y', 'b'): 1.0}```, then I tried to map the values by using ```df[['Type', 'subType']].map(ur_dict)``` and it gave me error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'```, then I tried ```(df[['Type', 'subType']].to_numpy()).map(ur_dict)```, it says ```AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'map'``` How can I turn it into 'turple' so that I can use ```map()```?

Comment: You are using the wrong syntax. Let me edit my answer to show you how to use 2 column values to perform the `map()` method give me a minute :D.

Comment: Sure. No worries :)